# Do I have to change directories and give permissions everytime I try to run a file directly from Terminal?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, python-3.6

I wrote some simple code that would would open google maps and would search for the address that you pass to it as an attribute.The name of the file is `mapit.py` The code is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
#! python3


import sys,webbrowser

a=sys.argv
b=a[1:]

main=' '.join(b)

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/' +str(main))
```

As you can see, this is designed to run from the Terminal. This is what I do when I try to run this program in Terminal:

`1 Save the file on the desktop 
2 Open terminal and change the directory to desktop 
3 Pass chmod +x mapit.py
4 Enter ./mapit.py Harvard University, USA`

And it works perfectly fine.

But is there a simple way to run `mapit.py` in the terminal without changing directories and giving permissions every time I want to run the file?

Comment: What? Once you've downloaded it once, why would you need to keep re-saving it and changing the permissions?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean @DanielRoseman

Comment: You've done it once and set the permissions, then run it. Why would you need to do anything the second time other than just run it again?

Answer (score 0):

To running scripts without changing directory, add scripts' location to the *PATH*. Lets say your dir name is *mapit/* under the home dir:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/mapit"
$ mapit.py
```

Adding *~/mapit* to the *PATH* like this is only temporary, however. It won’t stick across terminal sessions or system restarts. If you want to make your command permanently available on a system:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/mapit"' >> .profile
```

And one last thing, when you changed the permissions you dont need to change it over and over again to run the script.